# JSON error when I made update for Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

I was using JSON library in objective c and every thing was going great but now after making update with Xcode (now I'm using Xcode 4.4.1) I found there is a problem when I use the old lovely library to parse JSON, Xcode is telling me these error

[Click Here to see the error screen.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/87716877@N06/8026930815/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Can Any one give me a link to which JSON version should I use?
And what is these errors, cos when I face these type of errors I don't know what to do?

Comment: It says linker error, so maybe a look at the build phases 'Link Binary...' will help. Maybe a missig or ourdated Framework?

Comment: Did you add SBJSON as a nested project or just copy the source in? If it's a nested project you make need to update that projects settings.

Comment: i think some of your implementation files are not added into your build target/build phase.. check out that